# ¿Como llamar mi ruta UPDATE mediante el action del form en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy tratando de llamar la ruta de update mediante el action del form y no me manda ningún error pero aun así en la base de datos mi registro no se actualiza. Estoy usando el Route::resource de laravel.

Este es mi form:

```
 //Aqui quiero llamar la funcion
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/conceptos" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token();?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">idconcepto</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="idconcepto" value="2" >

          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">idgrupo</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="idgrupo" >

          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">titulo</label>
          <input type="" class="form-control" name="titulo" >

          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">sustento</label>
          <input type="" class="form-control" name="sustento" >

          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">periodicidad</label>
          <input type="" class="form-control" name="periodicidad" >

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>

      </form>
```

Mi  ruta

```
 Route::resource('/conceptos', 'Conceptos',['except' => ['edit','create']]);
```

Mi controlador

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'titulo' => 'required|max:150',
        'sustento' => 'required|max:45',
        'periodicidad' => 'required|max:20'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $validator->messages()
        ],400);
    }

    if($this->checkName($request->nombre,$id)){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Ya existe un concepto con el mismo nombre'],400);
    }

    $concepto = Concepto::where('estatus',1)->find($id);
    $concepto->fill($request->all());
    $concepto->save();

    return $concepto;
}
```

Comment: podrias hacer un dd al concepto despues de la linea   $concepto = Concepto::where('estatus',1)->find($id); para ver si realmente te trae el modelo correcto que necesitas. asi dd($concepto);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es que Laravel utiliza el verbo PUT o PATCH para los updates, por lo cual sería la primera modificación, además, no estás pasando el id (o llave) del concepto que quieres actualizar, idealmente utilizando Route Model Binding.

Si deseas seguir utilizando la URL y no el nombre de la ruta, esto debería funcionar:

```
<form method="PUT" action="http://localhost:8000/conceptos/<?php echo $concepto->id ?>" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Una mejor práctica es utilizar el nombre de la ruta, para que sea independiente de la url, por medio del helper route():

```
<form method="PUT" action="{{ route('conceptos.update', ['id' => $concepto->id) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Teniendo en cuenta que no he probado este código, es posible que debas hacer algunas modificaciones al método de tu controlador update, asumiendo que uses [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding), lo cual recomiendo ampliamente también. Por favor revisa con detalle la documentación de Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema va estar en esta linea

```
  $concepto = Concepto::where('estatus',1)->find($id);
```

Por que puede que el concepto que buscas no exista con estatus 1

entonces yo re recomiendo que lo hagas asi

```
$concepto = Concepto::where('estatus',1)->find($id);
if(is_null($concepto)){
  //No se puede acutualizar no cumple el filtro
  return redirect()->back();
}
$concepto->fill($request->all());
$concepto->save();
```

> Sin embargo recomiendo que imprimas el modelo antes de hacer el fill para ver si trae el modelo correcto quedando asi

```
$concepto = Concepto::where('estatus',1)->find($id);
dd($concepto); //esto te imprimira en pantalla el modelo
```

Comment: Ya cheque eso, en realidad mi problema es que no se como poner la ruta de update en el form en la parte del action, porque cuando le mando el id como parámetro me carga la función show y no el update.

Comment: @blidge en ese caso la respuesta de Shaz es correcta usando <form method="POST" action="{{ route('conceptos.update', ['id' => $concepto->id]) }}">

Comment: @blidge como adicional te recomiendo usar esta librería https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html

Answer (score 0):

Si tu formulario es una vista desde el método conceptos.show lo que pienso que esta fallando es la validación de tus datos, ya que dejaste vacío el atributo type de los input que quieres validar y recuerda que en las reglas que pusiste

`'titulo' => 'required|max:150', 'sustento' => 'required|max:45', 'periodicidad' => 'required|max:20'`

max:valor se interpreta de diferente modo de acuerdo al tipo de dato. Por tanto al no pasar la validación de los datos del formulario  de esta vista y repito suponiendo que la vista fuera de conceptos.show entonces te esta regresando la misma vista pero tampoco te esta enviando los mensajes del error de la validación.

Así que te recomiendo que primero pongas el atributo type correspondiente a tus datos en el formulario y que pruebes ya sea desactivando momentáneamente la validación para ver si el error proviene de ahí o que te cerciores del correcto funcionamiento de tu validación con los datos que le estas enviando. Siento que ese es el principal problema en este caso. Saludos cordiales.